# C++11 Variable narrowing with no GCC compiler warning

Tags: c++, c++11

The concept of narrowing seems pretty straight-forward. However, could someone please explain why some of the code below causes "narrowing" compiler errors and others don't?

This code produces errors where expected:

```
constexpr int a = 255;
unsigned char b = a;      // OK
unsigned char c = a + 1;  // Error... expected
```

This code doesn't produce errors, but may be ok:

```
int d = 256;
unsigned char e = d;  // Maybe OK because 'd' is not constexpr
```

This code should generate errors (unless I'm missing something):

```
int f = 42.0;  // Maybe OK because no fractional part
int g = 42.1;  // OK... should fail!!
constexpr float h = 42.7;
int i = h;     // OK... should fail???
```

I'm using g++ 4.6.2. I searched the GCC bug database and didn't find anything related. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's what "narrowing" means. Sehe's answer concerning initialization lists is the nearest issue I can think of.

Comment: +1 _interesting_ question. I was surprised by the findings in g++ :)

Comment: @KerrekSB That made sense until `int f = {42.7};` didn't generate any warning even with -Wall

Comment: @tdistler: nah, `int f = {42.7};` **is** using initializer lists.

Comment: I think to get C++11's protection against narrowing conversions you have to use the new initialization syntax `int f{42.7};`. C++11 is supposed to be backwards compatible so legacy code that already uses narrowing conversions with the old syntaxes still have to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be honest, with your samples I see little wrong.

However, there are a number of cases where the compiler seems to accept 'violations' of the standard conversion rules...:

#### Initializer lists (§ 8.5.4)

However I spotted this one in the standard:

For initialzer lists, the following is not allowed (§ 8.5.4, under **3.**)

```
int ai[] = { 1, 2.0 }; // error narrowing
```

Under **6.** it goes on to give a general list of examples:

> *[ Note: As indicated above, such conversions are not allowed at the top level in list-initializations.—end
>   note ]*

```
int x = 999; // x is not a constant expression
const int y = 999;
const int z = 99;
char c1 = x; // OK, though it might narrow (in this case, it does narrow)
char c2{x}; // error: might narrow
char c3{y}; // error: narrows (assuming char is 8 bits)
char c4{z}; // OK: no narrowing needed
unsigned char uc1 = {5}; // OK: no narrowing needed
unsigned char uc2 = {-1}; // error: narrows
unsigned int ui1 = {-1}; // error: narrows
signed int si1 =
{ (unsigned int)-1 }; // error: narrows
int ii = {2.0}; // error: narrows
float f1 { x }; // error: might narrow
float f2 { 7 }; // OK: 7 can be exactly represented as a float
int f(int);
int a[] = { 2, f(2), f(2.0) }; // OK: the double-to-int conversion is not at the top level
```

Interestingly, g++ 4.6.1 with `--std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic` catches **only one** of these violations:

```
    char c3{y}; // warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

---

#### Outside initializer lists...

I don't think the truncation of a float to an int is considered `narrowing`.

It is just a well-defined conversion, much like

```
int i = 31;
i /= 4;   // well defined loss of precision...   
i /= 4.0; // equally well-defined conversion from floating point to int
```

Comment: Thanks! Okay, so if this code `int f = {42.7};` also doesn't give an error, then would you agree there's a problem? BTW: no error on g++ 4.6.2.

Comment: @tdistler: AFAICT yes, that shoud not compile. (no error? I assume you mean no error message :))

Comment: "*I don't think the truncation of a float to an int is considered narrowing.*" The FDIS, §8.5.4/7 says otherwise: `A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion ... from a floating-point type to an integer type`. The relevant point is that narrowing conversions are legal outside of initializer lists.

Answer (score 1):

Floating points can get converted to ints:

> A prvalue of a ﬂoating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion trun-
>   cates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undeﬁned if the truncated value cannot be
>   represented in the destination type.

```
int f = 42.0;  // Equal to 42, 42 fits into int
int g = 42.1;  // Equal to 42, 42 fits
constexpr float h = 42.7;
int i = h;     // 42
```

Narrowing rules only applies to initializer lists.

```
unsigned char c = { 2.4 }; // narrowing

warning: narrowing conversion of ‘2.3999999999999999e+0’ from ‘double’ to ‘unsigned char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm reading Bjarne's explanation wrong [link](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#narrowing) (or it's out of date), but even the error case `int x3 = {7.3}` doesn't produce an error.

Comment: @tdistler I'm getting a pretty clear compiler warning with GCC. Not sure why it's a warning instead of an error.

Comment: Weird... I'm even compiling with -Wall

Answer (score 0):

This code produces errors where expected:

```
constexpr int a = 255;
unsigned char b = a;      // OK
unsigned char c = a + 1;  // Error... expected
```

This results in a narrowing error because:
1. (a + 1) results in an int rvalue
2.  the rvalue does not fit in the valid range of the char type

```
int d = 256;
unsigned char e = d;  // Maybe OK because 'd' is not constexpr
```

This code is not an rvalue being narrowed. It's an implicit cast from int to unsigned char.