# Narrowing conversion from char to uint8_t

Tags: c++, c++11, narrowing

Compiling the following snippet using C++11(demo [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4hGpMk%240)):

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    const uint8_t foo[] = {
        '\xf2'
    };
}
```

Will trigger a warning(at least on GCC 4.7), indicating that there's a narrowing conversion when converting `'\xf2'` to `uint8_t`.

Why is this? `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, which should be the same as `sizeof(uint8_t)`, shouldn't it?

Note that when using other char literals such as `'\x02'`, there's no warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although char doesn't necessarily have to be 8-bits long, that's not the problem here. You are converting from `signed char` to unsigned (`uint8_t`), that's the reason for the error.

This:

```
const int8_t foo[] = {
    '\xf2'
};
```

will compile fine.

Comment: `\xf2` is 242. That doesn't fit in a signed char, does it?

Comment: Now I'm wondering why this: `const uint8_t foo = '\xf2';` doesn't trigger any warnings.

Comment: `\xf2` equals to binary 11110010. This fits into a signed char as -14

Comment: `\xf2` has type `int` though.

Comment: @jrok Not in C++. In C, it is. In C++, it's `char`.

Comment: @icepack But isn't signed integer overflow undefined behavior (or has at least an unspecified reasult)?

Comment: @mfontanini That's a good question. There are related questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251059/c11-variable-narrowing-with-no-gcc-compiler-warning and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434140/narrowing-conversions-in-c0x-is-it-just-me-or-does-this-sound-like-a-breakin

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't see overflow here. `\xf2` is a valid value for signed char, it could've been written as -14, for example.

Comment: @icepack Since - assuming that `char` is 8 bit long, which it seems to be on OP's platform - `CHAR_MAX` is 127, and `0xf2` is more than 127 (`0x7f`), so there is indeed overflow.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm aware of that, but I thought hex escape sequence is  a multichar literal which do have type `int`. I looked in standard, and I see I was wrong, it has type `char` indeed.

Comment: BTW, your original code compiles without a warning on gcc 4.6.3: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1u38hL$7

Comment: @H2CO3 But you're interpreting 0xf2 as unsigned value. I'd say it's compiler job to interpret it as a signed value (it's constant after all) where MSB is the sign, and inject it into the code.

Comment: @icepack No, not quite. There's an implicit type conversion taking place.

Comment: @icepack: the standard says (2.14.3/4) "The value of a character
literal is implementation-deﬁned if it falls outside of the implementation-deﬁned range deﬁned for `char`". Which hex `f2` does, since its meaning in an escape sequence is the *number* 242, not the *bit pattern* `11110010`. So there's no portable way to write a character literal with negative value, the portable way to write this is `const int8_t foo[] = { -14 };`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at my system, the constant `\xf2` is overflowing, since it's out of range of a signed char. It's being represented as `-14` which is then implicitly converted to an unsigned int, giving a value of 4294967282. That's then narrowed to a `char`, producing this warning:

```
warning: narrowing conversion of ‘'\37777777762'’
```

Using `(unsigned char)'\xf2'` removes the warning.